# Incorrect cmake opencv lib path leads to failed compilation

Tags: ros, libopencv, cmake, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile `web_video_server` on a raspberry pi with all the `libopencv-*` packages installed.  Every time I try to run catkin_make_isolated, everything works fine up until make complains that the package requires `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.0.0`.  That package is from a local build of OpenCV that has since been removed with `make uninstall`, and the proper path should be to an older version installed through apt-get at `/usr/lib/libopencv*`.  How can I prevent cmake from using the old lib path of OpenCV?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202782/incorrect-cmake-opencv-lib-path-leads-to-failed-compilation/) by [GEOFBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/21592/geofbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you check whether `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` contains anything opencv related? Also (just to be sure): you restarted the entire build right? So `rm -rf devel_isolated/ build_isolated/`, then `catkin_make_isolated ..`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0